# How to sum values stored in an array of textboxes

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, sum

How to sum the values stored in an array of textbox using **javascript** and display it in a separate `<div id="hasil"></div>`.

Thank you all.

This is my javascript:

```js
function tambah() {
    var sum = 0;
    var cost = document.getElementsByName('jumlah[]');
    for (var i = 0; i < cost.length; i++)
    {
        sum += parseFloat(cost[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('hasil').value = sum;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="hitung" name="hitung">
            <label>Jumlah</label> <br> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">Rp.</span>
            <input name="jumlah[]" type="text" class="form-control" onChange="tambah();" >
            <span class="input-group-addon">,00</span><br>
            <span class="input-group-addon">Rp.</span>
            <input name="jumlah[]" type="text" class="form-control" onChange="tambah();" >
            <span class="input-group-addon">,00</span><br>
            <span class="input-group-addon">Rp.</span>
            <input name="jumlah[]" type="text" class="form-control" onChange="tambah();" >
            <span class="input-group-addon">,00</span>
            <div id="hasil"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is due to setting the value of the `#hasil` element. DIV elements do not have a `value` so you can't use `.value = sum;`.

Instead you can try:

```
document.getElementById('hasil').innerHTML = sum;
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/1gnk1we6/)

Answer (score -1):

```
function tambah(){
      var taxtva1 = $("#1").val();
      var taxtva2 = $("#2").val();
      var taxtva3 = $("#3").val();
      var total = Number(taxtva1) + Number(taxtva2) + Number(taxtva3);
     ("#hasil").text(total);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <html>
        <body>
            <form id="hitung" name="hitung">
    <label>Jumlah</label> <br> 
    <span class="input-group-addon">Rp.</span>
    <input name="sum" id="1" type="text" class="form-control" onChange="tambah();" >
    <span class="input-group-addon">,00</span><br>
    <span class="input-group-addon">Rp.</span>
    <input name="sum" id="2" type="text" class="form-control" onChange="tambah();" >
    <span class="input-group-addon">,00</span><br>
    <span class="input-group-addon">Rp.</span>
    <input name="sum" id="3" type="text" class="form-control" onChange="tambah();" >
    <span class="input-group-addon">,00</span>
    <div id="hasil"></div>
              </form>
          </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: OP didn't mention the use of JQuery. You haven't explained that you are using it. You have invalid code: `("#hasil")`